# Release date for MAAS 1.8

Tags: maas

Is there any official release date, or estimation, for MAAS 1.8?

In the [milestone page](https://launchpad.net/maas/+milestones) there is no info in *expected* column.

Answer (score 1):

we haven't yet finalized the 1.8 release plan but plan to have a beta out this month. Are there any specific features in 1.8 that you care about that are not in 1.7? We could look into backporting if necessary.

Comment: I want tag management from the web interface, but I have already answered in the mailing list (https://lists.launchpad.net/maas-devel/msg02075.html). Thanks!

Comment: FWIW, 1.8 has now been released: https://lists.launchpad.net/maas-devel/msg02107.html